# How to add array of struct to struct of array of struct in Spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have below example

```
val df_temp1 = Seq(
  ("1","Adam","Angra", "Anastasia")
).toDF("id","fname", "mname", "lname")
df_temp1.createOrReplaceTempView("df_temp1")

val df1 = spark.sql("""select id,named_struct('opi1',array(named_struct('data_description','fname','data_details',fname),named_struct('data_description','mname','data_details',mname),named_struct('data_description','lname','data_details',lname))) as pi, array(named_struct('data_description','fname','data_details',fname),named_struct('data_description','mname','data_details',mname), named_struct('data_description','lname','data_details',lname)) as opi2 from df_temp1""")
df1.printSchema
df1.show(false)
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
```

That gives below output schema

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pi: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- opi1: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- data_description: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- data_details: string (nullable = true)
 |-- opi2: array (nullable = false)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- data_description: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- data_details: string (nullable = true)
```

And below result

```
+---+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|id |pi                                                   |opi2                                               |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{[{fname, Adam}, {mname, Angra}, {lname, Anastasia}]}|[{fname, Adam}, {mname, Angra}, {lname, Anastasia}]|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

I want opi2 to be included along with opi1 in pi, So expected schema should look like this

```
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pi: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- opi1: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- data_description: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- data_details: string (nullable = true)
 |----|-- opi2: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |--   |--data_description: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |---- |--data_details: string (nullable = true)
```

And Expected Output will be two arrays opi1 and opi2 inside pi like below

```
+---+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|id |pi                                                                                                |
+---+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{[{fname, Adam}, {mname, Angra}, {lname, Anastasia}],[{fname, Adam}, {mname, Angra}, {lname, Anastasia}]}|
+---+-----------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------+
```

So basically adding existing column to struct (I am using Spark 2.3 by the way so any functions from Spark 2.4 cannot be used)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a new struct from `pi.opi1` and `opi2`

```
val df2 = spark.sql("select id, named_struct('opi1',pi.opi1, 'opi2', opi2) as pi from df1")

df2.show(false)
df2.printSchema
```

---

```
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|id |pi                                                                                                        |
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1  |{[{fname, Adam}, {mname, Angra}, {lname, Anastasia}], [{fname, Adam}, {mname, Angra}, {lname, Anastasia}]}|
+---+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pi: struct (nullable = false)
 |    |-- opi1: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- data_description: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- data_details: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- opi2: array (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = false)
 |    |    |    |-- data_description: string (nullable = false)
 |    |    |    |-- data_details: string (nullable = true)
```